# Original paper by Gauss on gaussian integers

Tags: math-history

Could anyone provide me with the title and date of Gauss's paper where he first introduces gaussian integers and proves their unique factorization? 
If you could also provide me with his exact proof it would be perfect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If in doubt, his results are in the *Disquisitiones*

Comment: I also have a vague memory of having seen it written in the Disquisitiones Mathematicae, but from what Wikipedia says he wrote it on [some other monographies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_reciprocity#Gauss_2). Probably the Disquisitiones I saw was really an edition that compiled a few of his writings together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gauss introduced the Gaussian integers in his $1832$ work named *Theoria residuorum biquadraticorum*. For translations of the latin text see [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2008/translations-of-gauss-work-on-gaussian-integers).

Comment: Thanks. Which was his proof exactly?

Comment: The proof of UFD ? With the Euclidean norm $a^2+b^2$ as usual, I think. But have a look at the english translations yourself.